# Restoring windows 7 system backup to UEFI or GPT

Tags: windows-7, windows, uefi, restore, gpt

I am forced to shift from my old HP dv6 3121nr Laptop to a new laptop (I am still to purchase) which comes with windows10 and GPT UEFI.

I want to take system backup (may be with software like AOMEI, EASEUS, or Acronis with Universal restore option that allows restoring to a different hardware)  and restore in the new computer so that I can continue my seamless same experience as I am using my old computer without needing to pass through hastle.

However, once I tried like this and faced failure. Can anyone suggest proper procedure to do this and if at all this is possible?

Comment: Backup your personal files only. Then obtain the installers for the software you may want to keep using, if still compatible with Windows 10. What you're asking about can't be done and shouldn't be done. Your new hardware was designed to work with Win10, not Win7 and Win7 is about to reach the end of its (supported) life. Just forget the past and move on.

Comment: if you don't want to register to "hide yourself", what's the point of showing your email here?

Comment: What was the process you tried before? how did it fail? We need that info to stop giving you the same advise as previously.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the operating system installed on a machine, the drivers in this operating system are related to this machine, and may not be suitable for other PCs or laptops, unless the hardware configuration information between the PCs is exactly the same, then the operating system installed on this PC can be taken directly to other PCs, or the hardware configuration information between the laptops is exactly the same, then the operating system installed on this laptop can be taken directly to other laptops.

If you have the same hardware configuration laptop, you can get the same operating system with ghost software. If the hardware configuration is different, it may make the new laptop blue screen.

So it is impossible to do it, we can only back up some of the required files on Windows 7 and copy them to the Win 10 operating system.

Comment: This. Mostly. It is *possible* to move the OS between computers. There is a licensing hurdle and there are existing drivers, but with enough care these can be dealt with or (mostly avoided). However the required levels of care to resolve the driver issues are very, very high, near to impossible. It is much, much simpler to re-install Windows than it is to carefully remove all of the old drivers and install new ones without seriously damaging the OS.